# Python Selenium Xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm using Xpath and having trouble pulling out what information I need from this HTML info to click this button:

```
[@id='domain-members']/div[@id='app']/div[@id='frameworkModule']/div[@id='header'][1]/nav[@class='navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-primary flex background']/div[@id='nav2']/ul[@class='flex no-padding height-50 list-style-none']/li[@class='dropdown dropdown-accordion nav-hover sysf-resources-module flex-1 flex']/span/a[@class='icon flex-1 flex justify-content-center align-items-center']
```

**my code is:**

```
folder = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@title='______']")
folder.click()
```

any help or resources to point me towards where I can better find the info I want would be a great help!

Comment: Can you share the actual HTML ? the one that you've shared looks like a xpath itself

Comment: @cruisepandey heres a snip:https://ibb.co/wp2b2SK Its a dropdown menu and i need to select All Files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This HTML is not built using `Select` and `options` tag, so one can not use `Select` class from `Selenium`.

Instead try to `click` directly :-

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='#resources']"))).click()
time.sleep(5)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "All Files"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thank you! I have an error message now                                                                                            Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Sserb/PycharmProjects/WeSnare/main.py", line 33, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='dropdown-menu']"))).click()
  File "C:\Users\Sserb\PycharmProjects\WeSnare\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Is page url public ?

Comment: Its not, unfortunately. Is there a specific thing i can look for for you in the HTML?

Comment: When you manually hover on this drop down,  what is the HTML code, also please give me in text format. This is the way to share in text format :- 
Press F12 in Chrome -> go to element section -> then right click on the element you want to share the outer HTML - > select copy and then outer HTML

Comment: <a href="#resources" class="icon flex-1 flex justify-content-center align-items-center" title="Files" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fas fa-briefcase fa-fw"></i></a>

Comment: Do one more thing:- 
Press F12 in Chrome -> go to element section -> do a CTRL  + F -> then paste `//a[@href='#resources']`  and see, if your desired element is getting highlighted. Also in the same search bar on the extreme right matching nodes count will be shown, 1/1 or 1/2, please let me know how many matching nodes do you see.

Comment: It does Highlight the icon for the dropdown menu - it says 3 matching nodes

Comment: and out of these three which one is ours ? 1st, 2nd or 3rd ? You can try `(//a[@href='#resources'])[1]` or `//a[@href='#resources'])[2]` or `(//a[@href='#resources'])[3]`. and see which index is highlighting the one we want.

Comment: The dropdown menu is 1

Comment: this should work, should click on the drop down, try `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='#resources']"))).click()`

Comment: Use the above code `time.sleep(5)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "All Files"))).click()`